# React Native alignSelf center and stretch to maxWidth?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have the following

```
<View style={{maxWidth: 700}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <Text>Left Item</Text>
    <Text>Right Item</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

which is working as I'd expect on a large device (vertical black lines are edges of emulator screen).

[image]

All I would like to do is center this on the screen.

When I attempt to do so by adding alignSelf: 'center' to the parent

```
<View style={{maxWidth: 700, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <Text>Left Item</Text>
    <Text>Right Item</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

the width is lost.

[image]

I assume this is because by default alignSelf it is 'stretch'.  Is there a way to both stretch the content to use maxWidth and center it on the screen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `flex:1` along with `maxWidth` to both make it stretch but limit the width to 700

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{flex:1, maxWidth: 700, backgroundColor:'red', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
        <Text>Left Item</Text>
        <Text>Right Item</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Not terribly important but alignItem: 'center' is not necessary here since since I only care about centering horizontally. It's interesting to me that setting {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}} on the parent view works but setting only {{alignItems: 'center'}} doesn't work.  I would have assumed both would do the same thing in terms of horizontal alignment.

Comment: Thanks for `flex: 1`

Answer (score 9):

Using `maxWidth` along with `width: '100%'` does the trick for me.

Comment: That is not an either or - are you saying your use both together?

Comment: Yes. `flex: 1` didn't work in my case, so I used `width: '100%'` together with a `maxWidth` of the desired value. This stretches the container to 100% of the window width until `maxWidth` is reached.

Comment: This is also the solution that worked for me.